# 2 timers arduino [ 2x millis() ]

Tags: c, arduino

I'm having a problem with this code. I know what the problem is, but I can't find a good solution.

I have two functions using `millis()` - `clock()` and `time()`.

The function `clock()` returns date and time and the function `time()` returns the time that another action is ON.

The problem is that I'm not able to store the time that the `time()` function is counting. When I call the function 2 times the time starts on 0:00.

I know it's because I'm overwriting the variable every time I call the loop, but I can't find a good solution for it. It seems stupid, but I have this problem for a while.

PS: I would like to have the time information every loop.

---

Expected results:

```
Start

2s: press 1 - clock = 2s, time = 0s.
5s: press 2 - clock = 5s, time = 3s.
15s: press 1 - clock = 15s, time = 3s.
20s: press 2 - clock = 20s, time = 8s.
```

My code:

```
void clock() {
  // ... function that returns date and time;
  // ... using millis();
}
void time(){
  if (first == 0){
    sec_aux = 0;
    min_aux = 0;
    UtlTime = millis();
    first = -1;
  }
  if(millis() - UtlTime < 0){
    UtlTime = millis();
  }
  else{
    sec_aux = int((millis() - UtlTime) / 1000);
  }
  if(sec_aux > 59){
    sec_aux = 0;
    min_aux++;
    UtlTime = millis(); 
  }
  sec = sec_aux;
  min = min_aux;
  Serial.println("TIME");
  Serial.print(min); Serial.print(":"); Serial.println(sec);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    inChar = Serial.read();
  }
  switch(inChar){
    case '1':
      time();
      clock();
      break;
    case '2':
      clock();
      first = 0;
      break;
    default:
      clock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I understood correctly you want a function that

1) you call once and it resets the counter
2) you call successively and tells you how much time passed
3) you can reset sometimes

If so, you have to ask yourself "how can I reset the timer?". IMHO the best solution is using a flag passed to the function.

And... avoid using the `millis` function twice ;)

And, BTW, I think you want to perform an action just once when you receive the serial data, so move the switch inside the test...

Here is a sample:

```
void time(bool reset){
    unsigned long currMillis = millis();
    if (reset){
        sec_aux = 0;
        min_aux = 0;
        UtlTime = currMillis;
    }   
    while ((currMillis - UtlTime) > 1000)
    {
        UtlTime += 1000;
        sec_aux++;
    }
    while(sec_aux > 59){
        sec_aux -= 60;
        min_aux++;
    }
    // Why do you duplicate the data?
    sec = sec_aux;
    min = min_aux;
    Serial.println("TIME");
    Serial.print(min); Serial.print(":"); Serial.println(sec);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        inChar = Serial.read();
        switch(inChar){
        case '1':
            // Show time measure
            time(false);
            clock();
            break;
        case '2':
            clock();
            // Start time measure
            time(true);
            break;
        default:
            clock();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Ok, then you want a "stoppable" stopwatch. What I suggest you is to detach the update from the serial interface, so you always have updated values. Or at least that's the way my head works :P

I modified some things. You should

1. init `lastMillis` to `millis()` in the `setup`
2. init `timeIsRunning` to the proper value
3. call `resetTime()` inside the `setup`

Here is the code:

```
void resetTime()
{
    msec = 0;
    sec = 0;
    min = 0;
}

void updateTime()
{
    unsigned long currStep = millis() - lastMillis;
    lastMillis += currStep;

    if (timeIsRunning)
    {
        msec += currStep;
        while (msec > 1000)
        {
            msec -= 1000;
            sec++;
        }
        while(sec > 59){
            sec -= 60;
            min++;
        }
    }
}

void printTime()
{
    Serial.println("TIME");
    Serial.print(min); Serial.print(":"); Serial.println(sec);
}

void loop()
{
    updateTime();

    if (Serial.available())
    {
        inChar = Serial.read();
        switch(inChar)
        {
        case '1':
            // Show time measure
            timeIsRunning = false;
            printTime();
            clock();
            break;
        case '2':
            clock();
            // Start time measure
            timeIsRunning = true;
            break;
        default:
            clock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, frarugi87. I think I didn't make myself understood. I have 2 different functions. One that keeps counting the time no matter what happens and another one that I'll call and it should start counting a second time.
I'll have 2 diferent moments: 1 - Just time that the programm is running. 2 -  Total time that the second function is "On". do you get the idea?

Comment: So you want that at time X you start the `time` function and, from that moment on, every call to the `time` function should write the time since X. Right? If so, then both my program and yours should be fine (in mine there are a few improvements I suggest you to use), if it is not please provide some examples then (i.e. the real output of the function vs the desired output)

Comment: Yeah, that's it. But i need to storage this time,t hat's the main problem. When I call the function twice I'm losing time of the first call (I'm not adding up, I'm replacing it).

Comment: Start
2s: press 1 - clock = 2s, time = 0s.
5s: press 2 - clock = 5s, time = 3s.
15s: press 1 - clock = 15s, time = 3s.
20s: press 2 - clock = 20s, time = 8s. 
That's what i want =]

Comment: Hey, after a while I got what I want to. I've just changed the the "switch" to work independently of something being sent by the serial.
Thank you so much! Just one question, where do I find documentation on the assignments:  -= +=, etc? I had never used them. Thanks again frarugi87!